# A really slow UPDATE to a MySQL server

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I am running a CMS, but this has nothing do to with it.

I have a simple query which is:

```
UPDATE e107_online SET `online_location` = 'http://page.com/something.php?', `online_pagecount` = 133 WHERE `online_ip` = '175.44.*.*' AND `online_user_id` = '0' LIMIT 1;
```

but the same query reported from my website support gives that:

```
User@Host: cosyclim_website[cosyclim_website] @ localhost [] 

Thread_id: 7493739 Schema: cosyclim_website 

Query_time: 12.883518 Lock_time: 0.000028 Rows_sent: 0 Rows_examined: 0 Rows_affected: 1 Rows_read: 1
```

It takes 12 (almost 13) seconds for a simple update query? Is there a way I could optimize it somehow? If I run it through PhpMyAdmin it takes 0.0003s.

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `e107_online` (
  `online_timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `online_flag` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `online_user_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `online_ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
  `online_location` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `online_pagecount` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `online_active` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  KEY `online_ip` (`online_ip`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: You sure that website is connected to same DB that PhpMyAdmin is?

Comment: Yes, I use a shared hosting and only 1 DB, because my website is a small one.

Comment: @Nikola Are you running phpMyAdmin on the live host or on your local machine? Make sure and tell me

Comment: @Nikola and how many records do you have in the table?

Comment: @itsols I use the phpMyAdmin which is provided by my hosting company. When I connect my website to the mysql server I use localhost as host, when I open phpMyAdmin it says "localhost".

I have no more than 30-50 records on that table. It's for the current online users, I also have a query which is 

DELETE FROM e107_tmp WHERE tmp_time < 1368887690 AND tmp_ip!='data' AND tmp_ip!='submitted_link'

So basically it's about the online users in a 5 min interval

Comment: @Nikola You say that when you open phpMyAdmin it says "localhost"... WHERE does it say that? In the address bar of the browser? I mean does the address bar show as **http://localhost/phpmyadmin...** or does it say something like **http://somedomain.com/.../phpmyadmin/...** ?

Comment: I have said "I use the phpMyAdmin which is provided by my hosting company", therefore I do not see how I can have it on my localhost. I have it on my website/cpanel/3rdparty/phpmyadmin or something like that. There it says "localhost", because the mysql server is on the same server as the website (probably)

Answer (score 3):

Your query is updating one row which meets certain criteria:

```
UPDATE e107_online
    SET `online_location` = 'http://page.com/something.php?', `online_pagecount` = 133
    WHERE `online_ip` = '175.44.*.*' AND `online_user_id` = '0'
    LIMIT 1;
```

Given that you have ip addresses, I'm guessing that this table is pretty big.  Millions and millions and millions of rows.  There are many reasons why an update can take a long time -- such as server load, blocking transactions, and log file performance.  In this case, let's make the assumption that the problem is finding one of the rows.  You can test this just by doing a `select` with the same conditions and see how long that takes.

Assuming the `select` is consistently slow, then the problem can probably be fixed with indexes.  If the table has no indexes -- or if MySQL cannot use existing indexes -- then it needs to do a full table scan.  And, perhaps the one record that matches is at the end of the table.  It takes a while to find it.

I would suggest adding an index on either `e107_online(online_ip)` or `e107_online(online_user_id, online_ip)` to help it find the record faster.  The index needs to be a b-tree index, as explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html).

One consequence of using an index is that the ip with the lowest matching value will probably be the one chosen.  I don't know if this lack of randomness makes a difference in your application.

Comment: I have added the table on my post. I do not have millions of records, I have < 50, because my website is not really that populated. As I have answered to @itsols I run a query on every page which is opened which is:

DELETE FROM e107_tmp WHERE tmp_time < 1368887690 AND tmp_ip!='data' AND tmp_ip!='submitted_link'

It is not my own system, it's e107, which is a free CMS, but their help on forums isn't something you can really rely on :/

Comment: I would also check for any type casting.  I noticed a online_user_id = '0' check.  If online_user_id is a numeric column, could MySQL be parsing '0' from string to integer for every row that it scans?  Could be small fish, but could be low-hanging fruit...

Comment: well user_id = 0 is used for people who are not logged in (guests), it's never been casted

Comment: @Brandon . . . The MySQL documentation is not 100% clear on this, but it does say "Strings are automatically converted to numbers and numbers to strings as necessary."  The danger is not that the constant would be converted to an int.  It is that the column would be converted to a string -- and then preclude the use of an index.  I'm guessing that MySQL does the right thing here.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just this query that is slow, or are queries from your website generally slower? phpMyAdmin is most likely running queries directly on the machine your database lives on, which means network latency is effectively 0ms. I would have suggested adding an index including the two columns in your WHERE clause, but with <50 rows that doesn't make any sense. This is going to come down to a blockage between your website and database server.

Also make sure you're not doing anything silly like running without connection pooling turned on (or creating a ton of connections unnecessarily). I've seen connection pools that had run out of space cause problems similar to this.

Comment: Well I have asked my hosting provider to show my why do I have such big mysql cpu time usage. And they gave me two slow queries - this one and another one (same type, same table etc). Usually I have around ~30-40 queries (< 60 for sure) per page and it takes (according to the CMS' built-in time usage: Render time: 0.1416 sec, 0.1159 of that for queries. DB queries: 31.